# Обновить состояние кнопки

Tags: javascript, меню, toggle, snapsvg

Доброго времени знатоки. Снова нуждаюсь в вашей помощи. Есть анимация svg кнопки "гамбургер". Работает чудесно, нажав на нее открывается и закрывается. Но мне надо добавить, чтобы можно было ее закрыть не нажимая на нее. А закрыв меню скажем свернув нажав в другом месте (не на иконку "гамбургера"). Чтобы запустился обработчик снова.

```
<script>
        (function nadavi() {

            function SVGHamburger( el, options ) {
                this.el = el;
                this.init();
            }

            SVGHamburger.prototype.init = function() {
                this.shapeEl = this.el.querySelector( 'span.morph-shape' );

                var s = Snap( this.shapeEl.querySelector( 'svg' ) );
                this.pathEl1 = s.select( 'path:nth-of-type(1)' );
                this.pathEl2 = s.select( 'path:nth-of-type(2)' );
                this.paths = {
                    reset : {
                        path1 : this.pathEl1.attr( 'd' ),
                        path2 : this.pathEl2.attr( 'd' )
                    },
                    open : this.shapeEl.getAttribute( 'data-morph-open' ).split( ';' ),
                    close : this.shapeEl.getAttribute( 'data-morph-close' ).split( ';' )
                };

                this.isOpen = false;

                this.initEvents();
            };

            SVGHamburger.prototype.initEvents = function() {
                this.el.addEventListener( 'click', this.toggle.bind(this) );
            };

            SVGHamburger.prototype.toggle = function() {
                var self = this,
                    paths = this.isOpen ? this.paths.close : this.paths.open;

                if( self.isOpen ) {
                    setTimeout( function() { classie.remove( self.el, 'menu-button--open' ); }, 200 );
                }
                else {
                    setTimeout( function() { classie.add( self.el, 'menu-button--open' ); }, 200 );
                }

                this.pathEl1.stop().animate( { 'path' : paths[0] }, 300, mina.easeout, function() {
                    self.pathEl1.stop().animate( { 'path' : self.paths.reset.path1 }, 800, mina.elastic );
                } );
                this.pathEl2.stop().animate( { 'path' : paths[1] }, 300, mina.easeout, function() {
                    self.pathEl2.stop().animate( { 'path' : self.paths.reset.path2 }, 800, mina.elastic );
                } );

                this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
            };

            new SVGHamburger( document.getElementById( 'menusToggleBt' ) );

        })();
```

Нажимая на мой код, чтобы закрыть гамбургер, он его закрывает (просто удаляет класс открытой. .removeClass("menu-button--open")

```
if (document.body.clientWidth<=978) {
    $(".navItem a").click(function(){
        $("#menusToggleBt").removeClass("menu-button--open");
```

Но когда я снова нажимаю на гамбургер, получается что он думает что открытый... И потому не добавляет класс menu-button--open. И за этого постоянно проблемы. 
Помогите как мне это правильно обработать. Чтобы скрыв меню (адаптивное выезжающее) оно и закрыло ПРАВИЛЬНО гамбургер.

Вот на всякий случай код самой кнопки: (без стилей)

```
<button id="menusToggleBt" class="menu-button">
                                                <span class="nadavi" style="margin-right: 5px;" >МЕНЮ</span><span id="morph-shape" class="morph-shape" data-morph-open="M3,20c0,0,12-4,27-4s27,4,27,4;M3,60c0,0,12,4,27,4s27-4,27-4" data-morph-close="M3,20c0,0,12,4,27,4s27-4,27-4;M3,60c0,0,12-4,27-4s27,4,27,4">
                                                    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 60 80" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                                                        <path d="M3,20C3,20,15,20,30,20C45,20,57,20,57,20"></path>
                                                        <line x1="3" y1="40" x2="57" y2="40"></line>
                                                        <path d="M3,60C3,60,15,60,30,60C45,60,57,60,57,60"></path>
                                                    </svg>
                                                </span>
                                    </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Что такое - "classie"?)

Не следует хранить отдельный флаг состояния `isOpen` - он неизбежно когда-нибудь рассинхронизируется с действительным состоянием объекта (что и происходит в Вашем коде). Если Вам понадобится выяснить открыт фрагмент или закрыт, используйте `$().hasClass`.

```
SVGHamburger.prototype.toggle = function() {
  var self = this,
      paths = $(this.el).hasClass('menu-button--open') ? 
        this.paths.close : this.paths.open;

  setTimeout(function() { $(self.el).toggleClass('menu-button--open'); }, 200);

  ...
```